# Revealing warning of deleted post

Tags: bug, review-audits

Recently while getting an review-audit I wanted to edit the post. A message like

```
This post was deleted. You can't edit deleted entries.
```

appeared. I think this shouldn't be displayed because it shows that we are in an audit.

Comment: It at least shows you're paying better attention and have a closer interest than the robo-reviewers it's trying to catch.